# Cloud storage with security

Tags: wordpress, server, cloud, storage

Which service is suitable according to my need?
I want to upload my videos to cloud so that anyone can watch those videos on my wordpress website but it must have some security measures like:

1. Anyhow, No one can download those videos .
2. Anyhow, no one can fetch links.
3. Downloader can't able to grab those videos.
4. There will be encryption technique for security purpose.
   Like Amazon services and many more which one I should choose so that I can calculate exact price for that plan. 
   In Amazon services, I am not exactly getting the final prices for video encryption services.

Comment: If you want someone to play the video, then there really isn't any way to stop them from making a copy of it, because the information required to play a video is also sufficient to copy it. If you're up for a challenge then the services you should look into are: Elastic Transcoder, AWS KMS, a 3rd party DRM license provider, CloudFront, S3. Also this url: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/drm.html will show you the complexity around digital rights management (DRM).

Comment: My main motive is to secure my uploaded videos to get downloaded or copied. So in this case, which rights are getting spoiled?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean. I think you're saying you want to prevent your videos from being downloaded or copied. If that is your goal it is very difficult because the information required to watch a video is enough to make a copy of the video. The best you can do is use digital rights management which will make it harder but not impossible for someone to download / copy your videos.

Comment: Ok thank you sir. But at last I struck at price calculation issue. It is difficult to predict Amazon services as per raising requests.